# For a .equals, is there an equivalent or alternative?

Tags: java

I'm supposed to write a program, where the user inputs a string where it counts for the number of each vowel, and how many non-vowels there are.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Strings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner MyScan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int countnon = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
            if (test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("a") || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("e")
                    || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("i") || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("o")
                    || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("u")) {
                break;
            } else {
                countnon++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(countnon + " occurences of non-vowels");
        MyScan.close();
    }
}
```

For some reason, the last piece of code, the one with the countnon variable, doesn't give the right value for the number. What did I do wrong? I tried to debug some of the code, but I couldn't find where I went wrong.

Comment: Your question and question title are completely at odds with one another. Please clarify, please do some debugging as well, and show your debugging results in your question.

Comment: You have posted way to much code in your question, which makes it unclear to us (and to future readers) exactly where the problem is.  Please reduce your problem code to 10 lines or less.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: is `break` being used correctly ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    int countnon = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < test.length(); i++) {
        if (test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("a") || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("e")
                || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("i") || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("o")
                || test.substring(i, i + 1).equals("u")) {
            break;  // HERE
        } else {
            countnon++;
        }
    }
```

You've used `break`, so you'll stop as soon as you find the first vowel. This means that you'll only get the right answer if all of your non-vowels appear before the vowels in the string.

Use `continue` instead.

Or, use nothing at all: an empty block would suffice.

Or, invert your condition:

```
if (!string.equals("a") && !string.equals("e") /* etc */) {
  countnon++;
}
```